# How to register users on my app with social auth?

Tags: oauth, python-social-auth

I am allowing users to register/login via facebook and username/passwd.
So if a user registers via fb, then how do I save the "User" instance without username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options:

**First**: allow null value in both fields.

**Second**: override some methods like this:

There is a function called `create_user` in `pipeline` which calls `create_user` of your user model's manager. You can override that method and create password by yourself:

```
def create_user(self, email, username, password, is_staff, is_superuser,
                 *args, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
    """
    now = timezone.now()
    if not username:
        username = ''  # or randomly generated string
    user = self.model(username=username, is_staff=is_staff, email=email,
                      is_active=True, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                      last_login=now, date_joined=now)
    user.set_password(password)   # this generates password
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

This will save a user with generated username and password. You can change it however you want.